# ASP.NET Identity - Find usuario por e-mail e senha

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-identity

Estou utilizando pela primeira vez o Asp.Net Identity, junto com o Entity Framework, e para criar um usuário, faço o seguinte código:

```
var identityUser = new IdentityUser
{
   UserName = viewModel.Nome.Replace(" ", "."),
   Email = viewModel.Email
};

IdentityResult resultado = userManager.Create(identityUser, viewModel.Senha);
```

Logo, o usuário é livre para inserir seu nome no primeiro campo `viewModel.Nome` e seu e-mail no segundo `viewModel.Email`. Para retornar esse usuário no momento de login, utilizo o seguinte código:

```
var usuario = userManager.Find(viewModel.Nome, viewModel.Senha);
```

Minha duvida é: É possível buscar o usuário por E-mail, e não por Nome? ou seja, no momento do `Find` trocar o `viewModel.Nome` por `viewModel.Email`?

Comment: Respondendo de forma simples, [sim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151641(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager%602.FindByEmailAsync(System.String)). Ou então, se quiser, a versão [síncrona](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.usermanagerextensions.findbyemail(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.FindByEmail%60%602(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D,System.String)).

Comment: @isaac usei uma abordagem com base no link que você passou, com algumas alterações. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido. Para tal, recuperei o usuário por e-mail, e logo após fiz o login utilizando seu name, da seguinte forma:

```
var retorno = userManager.FindByEmail(viewModel.Login);
var usuario = userManager.Find(retorno.UserName, viewModel.Senha);
```